# bash inhibit escaping in variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I did my finding and quoting command

```
FILES=$(find `pwd` -type f -print0 | grep -z --color=never '.\+\.cpp' | xargs -0 -I {} printf "%q " {})
```

Then if I do it simple

```
gcc $FILES
```

, it results in spliting input on whitespaces, quoting it and escaping single quotes made by `printf`.

What I have to do is

```
eval "gcc $FILES"
```

Is it possible to tell bash not to quote-escape `FILES` expansion in the first case?

Comment: why do you escape files with space? `printf "%q "` ?

Comment: you can `eval "gcc \$FILES"`, does that solve the issue?

Comment: @KamilCuk to escape special characters in the paths. `eval "gcc $FILES"` works fine, I am asking what can I do to `$FILES` expansion in `gcc $FILES` to prevent it from escaping during expansion.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. This works ok for me. Can you give an mcve or example where it fails? Maybe you want `eval "gcc $(printf "%q" $FILES)"` ?

Comment: Why aren't you simply using an array? You could write simply `files=( **/*.cpp )` (if you aren't overly concerned about stray directories, pipes, etc matching the glob), or `for f in **/*.cp; do [ -f "$f" ] && files+=("$f"); done` (if you are). (In both cases, you'll need `shopt -s globstar` to enable the recursive `**` pattern. Then it's just `gcc "${files[@]}"`

Comment: I usually add `nullglob` to code that uses `globstar`

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variables and command substitutions; this means that if there are escape characters in a variable's value, they get treated as regular characters, not shell syntax. You use quotes and escapes when representing data (e.g. filenames) on the command line, but embedding them *in* the data doesn't do the same thing.